# jQuery find checkbox and check/uncheck it

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

My `checkboxes` created in loop:

```
@foreach (L1 item in Model)
{
    <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="@(item.Name)" 
         class="clink" value="@(item.Name)"/>@item.ForeName</label></li>
}
```

And then I am using jQuery to check it:

```
 $('#cworks').prop('checked', true);
```

The above is not working. here is the generated html using firebug

```
<label class="checkbox"><input id="cworks" class="clink" value="cworks" type="checkbox">cworks</label>
```

Comment: So you have an element with the id of checkbox surrounding the checkbox? Don't you want a class selector?

Comment: Running your function after Dom.ready?

Comment: ID's are unique, so just `$('#Careworks_Map').prop('checked', true) ` should do it.

Comment: When debugging jQuery selectors, it's often helpful to see what the selector returns. In this case, it would be helpful context to add to the question.

Comment: why not inspect the generated `HTML`?

Comment: isherwood yes I am running it inside "$(document).ready(function ()", Surprisingly the html generated shows the checkbox exist but does not want to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you set a class `class="checkbox"` then in the jquery call you use an id `#checkbox input` so to make it work you should do:

```
$('.checkbox input[id="somestring"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Then if your `item.Name` is set with a prefix like `var item.Name` = `my_prefix`_somestring you can use a wildcard.

```
 $('.checkbox input[id=*"my_prefix"]').prop('checked', true);
```

If `item.Name` are unique (which I presume) then just do :

```
$('#Careworks_Map').prop('checked', true);
```

**EDIT**

**based on your update you should do that :**

```
$('#cworks').prop('checked', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/7FUBn/2/

Comment: I just did " $('#Careworks_Map').prop('checked', true); " as I am not using prefix - it does not work.

Comment: are you sure `Careworks_Map` is the right `id` name ? Is there any arrors in the console ? And is it unique ?

Comment: Yes I have updated my question by printing the html - pls have a look

Answer (score 1):

If the checkbox has an "id", then that is all you need to select it.

```
$('#Careworks_Map').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

ID’s should be unique. So it’s enough (and most efficient) to use that ID as a selector:

```
$('#Careworks_Map').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an id selector while you have to use a class selector :

```
$('.checkbox input[id="Careworks_Map"]').prop('checked', true);
```

You can also select directly the id of the checkbox you want to modify:

```
$('#Careworks_Map').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":checkbox input[id='Careworks_Map']").attr("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the `<label>` is declaring a `class="checkbox"` so you need to search for class with a period `.` and then target the inner checkbox

```
$('#checkbox input[id="Careworks_Map"]').prop('checked', true); // wrong

$('.checkbox input[id="Careworks_Map"]').prop('checked', true); // right
```

Comment: You should update your question to show the HTML generated by the `foreach()` loop because jQuery interacts with the HTML DOM and not whatever language is running the loop

Answer (score 0):

Use id instead of class

$('#Careworks_Map').prop('checked', true);